# Generate xpath from node using xslt 2

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

To generate the xpath for each node in a xml file and add this path as attribute to each node, I found some help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38590630/add-attribute-to-each-xml-node-xslt/38590848?noredirect=1#comment64578010_38590848). The xslt file should look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:attribute name="xpath">
        <xsl:for-each select="ancestor-or-self::*">
          <xsl:value-of select="concat('/',local-name())"/>
          <!--Predicate is only output when needed.-->
          <xsl:if
            test="(preceding-sibling::*|following-sibling::*)[local-name()=local-name(current())]">
            <xsl:value-of
              select="concat('[',count(preceding-sibling::*[local-name()=local-name(current())])+1,']')"
            />
          </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Now I'm interested in a more compact way using xslt 2.0. For example in the following xslt file I have two function createXPath and getXpath. The first one returns a path with node names and the second returns the corresponding number. Is it possible to combine those in smart way?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:func="http://www.functx.com">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="xpath">
            <xsl:value-of select="func:getXpath(.)"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

   <xsl:function name="func:createXPath" >
    <xsl:param name="pNode" as="node()"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$pNode/ancestor-or-self::*/local-name()" separator="/"/>
  </xsl:function>

  <xsl:function name="func:getXpath">
  <xsl:param name="pNode" as="node()"/>
   <xsl:value-of select="$pNode/ancestor-or-self::*/(count(preceding-sibling::*) + 1)" separator="/" />
</xsl:function> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining the two functions is rather trivial - for example, you could do:

```
<xsl:function name="func:path" >
    <xsl:param name="target" as="element()"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="for $step in $target/ancestor-or-self::* return concat(name($step), '[', count($step/preceding-sibling::*[name() = name($step)]) + 1, ']')" separator="/"/>
</xsl:function>
```

However, this method is quite inefficient, as it has to traverse the tree repeatedly. Consider instead:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:param name="path"/>
    <xsl:variable name="my-path">
        <xsl:value-of select="$path"/>
        <xsl:text>/</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
        <xsl:text>[</xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::*[name() = name(current())]) + 1"/>
        <xsl:text>]</xsl:text>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="xpath">
            <xsl:value-of select="$my-path" />    
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates>
            <xsl:with-param name="path" select="$my-path"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which takes advantage of XSLT's recursive processing model.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of points.

(a) There is no such thing as "the XPath of a node". Some people, when they use such a term, will mean a path like `a/b/c`, others will mean `a[1]/b[5]/c[6]`, and others will mean a path that is fully namespace-qualified by using predicates at each level that test namespace-uri().

(b) XPath 3.0 provides a function path() which returns an XPath expression of this kind; it uses the EQName syntax `Q{uri}local` to ensure that element names are context-free.

(c) My approach to getting the kind of path you are generating would be

```
<xsl:function name="f:path" as="xs:string">
  <xsl:param name="e" as="element(*)"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="ancestor-or-self::*/concat(
    '/',
    name($e),
    concat('[',f:index($e),']')[. ne '[1]']
  )" separator=""/>
</xsl:function>

<xsl:function name="f:index" as="xs:integer">
  <xsl:param name="e" as="element(*)"/>
  <xsl:sequence select="count(preceding-sibling::*[name()=name($e)])+1"/>
</xsl:function>
```

and then

```
<xsl:copy>
  <xsl:attribute name="path" select="f:path(.)"/>
  ....
</xsl:copy>
```

Comment: I don't think you have tested these.

Comment: I very rarely test code samples. I think it's important that the reader should understand the code rather than just using it verbatim, and leaving the odd error helps to ensure that.